# I'm in doubt about my line of reasoning on a problem involving volume

Tags: geometry, solution-verification

I'm learning to solve math problems, but I often find myself stuck in a situation. However, I always try different ways to solve the problem. I worked on a problem, came to an answer, but don't know if the answer is correct.
I would like someone to look into the question and my way of thinking, to tell me if I have arrived at the right answer and if I am thinking the right way. By the way, I would like to receive tips, if possible.

**Question**

An ice cream factory uses plastic packaging in the shape of a straight rectangular parallelepiped. Internally, the package is 10cm high and has a base of 20cm by 10cm. In the process of making ice cream, a mixture is placed in the package in a liquid state and, when taken to the freezer, its volume is increased by 25%, with a creamy consistency.

Initially, a chocolate flavor mixture is placed in the package with a volume of 1000cm³ and, after this mixture becomes creamy, a strawberry flavor mixture will be added, so that, at the end of the freezing process, the package is completely filled with ice cream, without overflowing.

The maximum volume, in cm³, of the strawberry flavor mixture that should be placed in the packaging is:

a) 450.
b) 500.
c) 600.
d) 750.
e) 1 000.

What I tried:

I calculated the internal volume of the package, as a parallelepiped, multiplied the 3 factors, obtaining as a result:

10cm x 10cm x 20cm = 2000cm³

Therefore, the internal volume of the packages is 2000cm³.

I paid attention to the keywords of the question:

*In the process of making ice cream*, *a mixture* is placed in the package in a liquid state and, *when taken to the freezer*, *its volume is increased by 25%*, with a creamy consistency.

I then realized that the volume of the mixture is increased when placing it in the package.

A mixture of chocolate flavor was placed in the packaging, with a volume of 1000cm³, and I see that I must increase 25% of this volume.

*25% of 1000cm³ = 250cm³*

1250cm³ volume is occupied, out of a total of 2000cm³

*a strawberry flavor mixture will be added, so that, at the end of the freezing process, the package is completely filled with ice cream, without overflowing*

Thus, there is still 750cm³ to be added to the package.

The question is: the maximum volume, in cm³, of the strawberry flavor mixture that should be placed in the packaging is...

I looked at the alternatives, calculated 25% of 600cm³, because if I were to add the strawberry mixture with 600cm³, I would have to calculate 25% of the increased volume, that is, the mixture always has a 25% increase.

25% of 600cm³ = 150cm³.

So:

Total = 2000cm³
Found = 1000cm³ + 250cm³ + 600cm³ + 150cm³ => 2000cm³

Therefore, the correct alternative is c) 600. At least, according to my reasoning.

I would like to know if the answer I found is correct and if my way of thinking makes sense. Sorry for the bad English.

Comment: That would be my answer too.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Glad to know, thanks!

Comment: You are correct, but do not explain how you got $600 cm^3$.  You would divide $750/1.25=600$ to do that.  You verified that $600$ works just fine.

Comment: @RossMillikan You're right. In this part I didn't know what to do and I tested the alternatives, to see what it would be. Sorry to ask, I have no mathematical knowledge, but why divide by 1.25? I didn't understand this, I appreciate it if you can explain

Comment: "but why divide by 1.25?" Total volume that would be occupied by strawberry mixture (at the end of freezing process)= $100\%$ of (Volume occupied initially by the liquid strawberry mixture)+ $25\%$ of (Volume occupied initially by the liquid strawberry mixture)=$125\%$ of (Volume occupied initially by the liquid strawberry mixture). You were asked to find the volume of **liquid** strawberry mixture so that the total volume after freezing, i.e., $125\%$ of liquid strawberry mixture becomes equal to $750\:cm^3$(filling the container completely by filling the remaining space which is $750\:cm^3$)

Comment: So, here's what you've got:  $125\%$ of (Volume of liquid strawberry mixture)= $750\:cm^3$. This implies $1.25×$ required volume= $750\:cm^3$. Therefore, required volume = $\frac{750}{1.25} \:cm^3$ (divided both sides of equation by $1.25$)

Comment: @AmanKushwaha That makes sense. Thank you so much!